# Hide/remove/change color of a canvas circle When toched in Android

Tags: android, canvas, geometry

this is my first question here, so maybe I'll make some mistakes.

I want to create an Android app for touch test, and draw a cross on the screen, however I'm succeeded to draw cross, but now I want to implement test screen login.

What I want to do is that, When user clicks on any circle it should be removed/hidden or change color to transparent.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

this is the link to my code.

https://github.com/akhlaqshah36/stackoverflow_questions/blob/master/drawCicles

and attached screenshot.

[image: Circles drawn on a canvas]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using some formulas of distance and Using Pointer objects.

check the solution here if someone need it.

[Solution Link drawing cross in canvas](https://github.com/akhlaqshah36/drawingX/blob/master/UsingSlope.java)